# What can cause XP to shutdown the moment you log in?

Tags: windows-xp, login, shutdown

Investigating a possible data theft:
I always switch off my PC before leaving office. This morning I found the switches on and the PC on too. The screen was locked, so when I logged in with my username and password, I was logged in, and the moment I logged in, the PC started shutting down. No viruses in the system.

The network allows us to log into any PC using our id and password, but if we're not logging into our own PC, we can't access any of the files of somebody else's PC we logged into.

I'm suspecting that either someone logged into my system with my id and password, or they logged in using their id and password (if they did, a new folder would have got created in Documents and settings with their name, but it didn't) and the PC didn't shutdown completely when they left.

The other possibility is that I didn't shutdown my PC properly, because I have a vague memory of giving a shutdown command and the PC wasn't shutting down because it could not end Winamp. I do remember manually ending Winamp and the blue shutdown screen coming up.

So what kind of a situation can cause the PC to start shutting down the moment one logs in?

Comment: I dunno, but give me physical access to the computer and BIOS and I can get your username/password. Best way to protect against this in the future is to password protect the BIOS, don't allow USB/CD booting, put a lock on the case and encrypt the hard drive.

Comment: I've seen this when Windows doesn't shutdown due to installing updates... The system doesn't power down after, just reboots. Then the PC being left at a login prompt hybernates, causing it to appear 'locked' when powered on. PoE/WoL might have caused it to come back to life...

Comment: Is it just one user, or all users?  Is it just one computer or all computers?  Can the user in question log into other computers?  Can other users log into the problem user's system?  How about in Safe Mode?  What have you tried/checked already? Have you looked at the Event Logs?

Comment: @HaydnWVN: ok, but that doesn't explain why it started shutting down the moment I logged in.   techie007: Didn't know about event logs. Will surely get a look at them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you somehow locked the computer before it had shut down (or perhaps the screensaver did it if the shutdown was waiting for winamp to do something) and the shutdown was paused until you unlocked it again. Try to lock the computer with win+l after you hit shutdown to see if you can do it again.

Comment: No. Even if many applications are open and shutdown takes a while, I'm not able to lock the computer after the shutdown command is issued.

Comment: However, when I used `shutdown -s`, the shutdown countdown began, I was able to lock the screen with win+l and at the end of the countdown, the screen lock automatically got removed and the PC didn't shutdown. I was able to use it normally until I gave it a normal shutdown.